# Macbook Pro producing mail in terminal. How can I stop this?

Tags: terminal, mail.app, bash

Terminal has been producing mail from an unknown script that I cannot track down. Message below:

[image]

Any ideas on how to stop this from sending me messages?

Comment: it's a cron job. See `crontab -l`.

Comment: Thank you! Learned something new today and removed cron job with cronjob -r.